# How to get list of URLs in a specific pattern?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am new in Scrapy. I crawl this web: https://masothue.vn

I get list of URLs like these

```
https://masothue.com/4700283907-hop-tac-xa-hop-tac-xa-ha-giang
https://masothue.com/2200794515-cong-ty-tnhh-cuc-tuan
https://masothue.com/0107858721-hop-tac-xa-dich-vu-nong-nghiep-thon-bac-ha
https://masothue.com/1701974147-nguyen-thi-thanh-xuan-my-dat
```

`4700283907`, `2200794515`, `0107858721`, `1701974147` always has 10 character numbers.

regex pattern is `https://masothue.com/` + unique 10 numbers string. How to archiev that?

Comment: `r'masothue.com\/\d{10}'`

Comment: because I am new commer, please write for me few lines of code in answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not clear whether you want match each line or all lines as a whole.
The code is for each line:

```
import re

s = 'https://masothue.com/4700283907-hop-tac-xa-hop-tac-xa-ha-giang'
print(re.search(r'masothue.com\/(\d{10})', s).group(1))
# 4700283907
```